# Google's resumable video upload status API endpoint for Google Drive is failing with HTTP 400: "Failed to parse Content-Range header.":

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-app-engine-python

In order to resume an interrupted upload to Google Drive, we have implemented status requests to Google's API following this guide. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload#resume-upload

Request:

```
PUT
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=UPLOAD_ID HTTP/1.1 
Content-Length: 0 
Content-Range: bytes */*
```

It works perfectly in most of the cases. However, the following error occurs occasionally and even retries of the same call result in the same erroneous response.

Response:

```
HTTP 400: "Failed to parse Content-Range header."
```

We are using the google.appengine.api.urlfetch Python library to make this request in our Python App Engine backend.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I could replicate this issue using cURL

```
curl -X PUT 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=UPLOAD_ID' -H 'Content-Length: 0' -vvvv -H 'Content-Range: bytes */*'
```

Response:

```
*   Trying 172.217.25.138...
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (172.217.25.138) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.googleapis.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=*.googleapis.com
*    start date: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 08:54:00 GMT
*    expire date: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 08:54:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=Google Inc,CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> PUT /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=UPLOAD_ID HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Range: bytes */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< X-GUploader-UploadID: UPLOAD_ID
< Content-Type: 
< X-GUploader-UploadID: UPLOAD_ID
< Content-Length: 37
< Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 22:45:58 GMT
< Server: UploadServer
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.googleapis.com left intact
Failed to parse Content-Range header.
```

Comment: Does it fail when the fist chunk is updated? In this case, for your first iteration, try using "Content-Range: bytes 0 - * / *".